# how to style same element with different CSS properties in styled-components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

how can i style same type of elements but diffrent ones with diffrent css properties in styled components ?
for example

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

with knowledge i have i can do

```
 export const StyledDiv = styled.div`
color:red;
`
```

and change `<div></div>` to `<StyledDiv></StyledDiv>`
but what if I want to change each of these divs with different styles? for example, I want one of them to have the color blue one and of them to have the color red
and these 2 elements are just for example to show you the meaning
now imagine a page with 10s of divs each with different style
What's the best way to deal with them?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass props to the styled component like so:

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.color};
`;
```

And in your component:

```
  return <StyledDiv color="red">...</div>;
```